# Flutter & Dart : How to take out 5 url string into an Array from Json List

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am super noon in programming and I have following issue.
I am trying to retrieve only 5~6 thumnailUrls as string array from following Json.

But, i spent whole week to figure out but I couldn't make it work. Maybe I found it but not properly understood it.

Here are my codes with data model

```
class TestData {
  int albumId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String url;
  String thumbnailUrl;

  TestData({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  TestData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    albumId = json['albumId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    url = json['url'];
    thumbnailUrl = json['thumbnailUrl'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['albumId'] = this.albumId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['thumbnailUrl'] = this.thumbnailUrl;
    return data;
  }

}
```

And here is my main

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:carlousel_test/model.dart';

Future<List<TestData>> fetchBanner(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');

  return compute(parseBanner, response.body);
  //  return response.body;
}

List<TestData> parseBanner(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<TestData>((json) => TestData.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

//// you can ignore this part 
final List<String> testList = [];

List<String> countBanner(List<TestData> countBanner) {
  int count = countBanner.length;
  if (count > 5) count = 5;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    testList.add(countBanner.elementAt(i).thumbnailUrl);
  }

  return testList;
}
///// til here cause i don't even know what i am doing here.


final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

final Widget placeholder = Container(color: Colors.grey);

final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                    Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
//  List<TestData> banners;

  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Carousel Slider',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.teal),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel Demo')),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Carousel With Indecator'),
                  CarouselWithIndicator(),
                ])),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: FutureBuilder<List<TestData>>(
                future: fetchBanner(http.Client()),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CarouselSlider(
                        autoPlay: false,
                        height: 300.0,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        initialPage: 0,
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        items: snapshot.data.map((i) {
                          return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                              child: Image.network(i.thumbnailUrl,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            );
                          });
                        }).toList());
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you see the code I like to replace following(the imglist) with Json from internet(testList from TestData).

```
final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];
```

I've looked at lots of articles but since i have lacked basic knowledge couldn't find thing that is working for mine.  Thanks ahead~!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve with this? Do you want to have placeholders for your images that are being fetched from the internet? If this is the case, you can use `FadeInImage` widget.

Comment: Like I said above I am trying to fetch 5~6 Urls like imgList from the TestData's thumnailUrl into testList.  Not the placeholder.  I am not able to Create List<string> that is fetched from internet.

Comment: My issue is about Parsing the data.  To be more specific, I would like to take out the imgList above to TestList that is fetched via internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your code (just `fetchBanner` function) and removed the `parseBanner` function. I have deliberately kept the changes to a minimum so most of your code remains intact.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class TestData {
  int albumId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String url;
  String thumbnailUrl;

  TestData({this.albumId, this.id, this.title, this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  TestData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    albumId = json['albumId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    url = json['url'];
    thumbnailUrl = json['thumbnailUrl'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['albumId'] = this.albumId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['thumbnailUrl'] = this.thumbnailUrl;
    return data;
  }
}

Future<List<TestData>> fetchBanner(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');

  List images = json.decode(response.body);
  var data = images.map((image) => TestData.fromJson(image)).toList();

  return data;
}

//// you can ignore this part 
final List<String> testList = [];

List<String> countBanner(List<TestData> countBanner) {
  int count = countBanner.length;
  if (count > 5) count = 5;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    testList.add(countBanner.elementAt(i).thumbnailUrl);
  }

  return testList;
}
///// til here cause i don't even know what i am doing here.


final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

final Widget placeholder = Container(color: Colors.grey);

final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                    Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
//  List<TestData> banners;

  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Carousel Slider',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.teal),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel Demo')),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Carousel With Indecator'),
                  CarouselWithIndicator(),
                ])),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: FutureBuilder<List<TestData>>(
                future: fetchBanner(http.Client()),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CarouselSlider(
                        autoPlay: false,
                        height: 300.0,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        initialPage: 0,
                        viewportFraction: 1.0,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        items: snapshot.data.map((i) {
                          return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                              child: Image.network(i.thumbnailUrl,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            );
                          });
                        }).toList());
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~! I made it work with your parsing fix.